# Two UIScrolleView On View

Tags: ios, iphone

```
self.first = [[UIScrolleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 375, 667)];
self.first.delegate = self;
self.first.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.first.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, 667 * 2);
[self.view addSubview:self.first];

self.second = [[UIScrolleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 667)];
self.second.delegate = self;
self.second.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.second.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375 * 2, 667);
self.second.first = self.first;
[self.view addSubview:self.second];
```

**first** is vertical, **second** is horizontal, now my question is:

When I vertical scroll, **second** always get gestures, becase of **second** is above **first**, the **first** can't scroll, some one have idea? Thanks in advince.

Comment: You'll need to be more precise in what you want to achieve. Your `first` scrollview won't scroll since it's behind the `second` scrollview - depending on what you want to achieve, you can either set their frames to not overlap, or add one of the scrollviews as a subview to the other.

Comment: yes, Similar to the snapchat home page, left and right scroll, up and down scroll, I see the snapchat layer, in one view have two scrollview, one up, one down.

Comment: When scrolling `first` vertically, should `second` remain fixed on the top, or should it scroll along with first (eventually going offscreen)?

Comment: Don't change the position of the two scrollviews, I use - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event, can't handle the direction.

Comment: why you are not use of ContainerView for it?

Comment: Can you say something in detail? What is ContainerView?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout1 = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout1.scrollDirection =  UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
UICollectionView *collectionView1 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout1];


UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout2 = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout2.scrollDirection =  UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
UICollectionView *collectionView2 = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 2 scroll views to have a fixed position (non-dependent of each others' scrolling), all you need to do is set their frames not to overlap.
An example below:

```
// assuming second needs to be placed on top, scrolls horizontally
self.second = [[UIScrolleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 375, 200)]; // set the height to it's maximum vertical content height
self.second.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.second.frame.size.width * 2, self.frame.size.height); // 2 horizontal pages

// first is on bottom, scrolls vertically
self.first = [[UIScrolleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.first.frame.size.height, 375, 667-self.first.frame.size.height)]; // fill remaining space on the bottom
self.first.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.first.frame.size.width, self.first.frame.size.height * 2); // 2 vertical pages
```

Comment: if the two scrollviews is overlaped, can't realize ??

Comment: If you really need to have them overlapping, both having full screen size, `hitTest:` should work. You might also need to subclass the scrollviews and overwrite `pointInside:withEvent:` method, such that the scrollview that's on top ignores some of the touches.

Comment: in hitTest: can't determine the direction. not sure when horizontal scroll, when vertical scroll.